# Firefox: use ctrl-n and ctrl-p to select the next/previous item in the Awesome Bar

Tags: mac, firefox

Is it possible to setup the Awesome Bar (and search engine suggestions) in Firefox on Mac so that ctrl-n and ctrl-p will select the next/previous item? (this is the default for most Mac lists)

Comment: Related: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/802233

Comment: Also: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=354637